# How do I get 16-bit programs to work on a 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, compatibility, 16-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why 64 bit OS can't run a 16 bit application?](https://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application)

When trying to play an old game, Skyroads for instance, I get the following error message:

> The version of this file is not
>   compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you
>   need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit)
>   version of the program, and then
>   contact the software publisher.

If I understand it correctly, Skyroads is a 16-bit program which is not supported in a 64-bit operating system? Is it impossible to get it running on a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question as it's a little different to "*Why 64 bit OS can't run a 16 bit application?*". The linked thread covers the "Why" but this one covers the practical solutions to dealing with the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few options, depending on the kind of program you need to run:

- For 16-bit DOS games, you can try [DOSbox](http://www.dosbox.com/) or [MS-DOS Player](http://takeda-toshiya.my.coocan.jp/msdos/)
- For 16-bit Windows applications (for Windows 1.x, 2.x, 3.0, 3.1, etc.) there's [winevdm](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm). It also provides some amount of DOS emulation.
- If none of the above work for your purpose, you may need to run a virtual machine (VM) with the full operating system of your choice (DOS, Windows, etc.). [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [VMWare Player](https://www.vmware.com/au/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) are commonly used for virtual machines.

Comment: DirectX for 16-bit programs doesn't even exist.

Comment: @grawity: Correct, but the underlying GDI display driver was 16 bit back then... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably install this in xp mode of windows 7. You can download and install xp mode from microsoft. It will function similar to a virtual machine. I think this works in Windows 7 pro and above but there may be some hackery you can perform to get to function in win 7 Home.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, it is not possible to run 16-bit application natively under Windows x64.  The long answer is yes.  If you're willing to try something like [XPMode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) or other [Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualization) software -- you can get it to work.

Comment: Wrong answer ! [Because the short answer is yes](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm).

Comment: Thank you, @user2284570.  The linked GitHub solution did not exist when the question was originally answered.  Perhaps you would be kind enough to edit the answer with some information on the solution you've mentioned, including details around how well it works in gaming scenarios.

Comment: I tried it on LucasArts Installer, and I didn t noticed a difference than on 32  bits with ntvdm.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to try running it on a 32 bit os in [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Vmware player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).

Comment: Or [otvdm](https://github.com/otya128/winevdm) which is an unofficial replacement of Ntᴠᴅᴍ on 64 bits Windows.