# How to make an extremely old app run on 64bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, compatibility

I have a very old application designed for Windows 3.1. I have been able to use this application on Windows 7, however, that was Windows 7 32bit. Now I have since re-installed Windows to 64bit, and this application does not work, saying it's incompatible. I have tried running the application (and its other side-applications) in Windows '95 mode, but still the same message.

How can I run this old app on 64bit Windows?

For the record, the application is a game called "Sim Tower"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run an old 16-bit DOS application under Windows 7 64-bit?](http://superuser.com/questions/333103/is-it-possible-to-run-an-old-16-bit-dos-application-under-windows-7-64-bit), http://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install and run it, with Dosbox and the Windows 3 for dosbox.

1. Download [Dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/)
2. Download [Windows 3 for dosbox](http://files.abandonia.com/extras/Programs/Windows%203%20for%20DOSBox.rar)

   **Attention**: You have to have a license for Windows 3, that you are allowed to use it. The download is only there, because you can't find an official-download from microsoft itself.
3. Unzip both archives in **one** new folder.
4. Add a new folder to this folder and name it, `Simtower`.
5. Now add all the files from Sim Tower to this folder.
6. Start dosbox.
7. Now execute the following command at the dosbox-commandline:

   > `mount c c:/your/path/where/you/have/dosbox/installed`
8. Change to the c drive by simply writing: `c:`in the dosbox-commandline.
9. Launch `windows.bat` inside the dosbox.
10. Windows 3 will now boot.
11. Open the folder `Main`->`File Manager`.
12. Now there should be a `Simtower`-folder.
13. Open it and launch the `setup.exe`.
14. Now just restart Windows 3, and you can run Simtower.

Of course, this will work with other Windows 3-programs as well.

[Source of Windows 3 for dosbox.](http://www.abandonia.com/vbullet/showthread.php?t=27770)

Comment: Excellent (except no install / setup, it runs stand-alone)

Comment: @JerryDodge Thx, good to know. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If it is a Windows 3.1 application, it is a 16bit application, not a 32bit one. Windows 7 64bit does no longer have a 16bit sub-system. So you can not run this app directly. You can install XP-Mode to run Windows XP on top of Windows 7 and then run your app in that XP virtual machine.

Comment: Please note that the free "Windows XP Mode" is only available for Windows 7 Professional and higher.

Comment: Otherwise, another option would be Oracle Virtual Box, or equivalent virtual machine software - running any other version of Windows which supports this.

Comment: @JerryDodge Yep, but then you'll need to buy a Windows XP license. There is a possibility to use DOSBox but then Windows 3.11 (also with license?) has to be installed on top of that because this game needs Windows.

Comment: @Rik Yup, I edited my comment to point that out (although the license should be obvious :-) )

Comment: @Rik windows 7 Pro and higher, but not Windows 8 of any flavour. :)