# 64-Bit in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get 16-bit programs to work on a 64-bit Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/264090/how-do-i-get-16-bit-programs-to-work-on-a-64-bit-windows)
>   [Is it possible to run an old 16-bit DOS application under Windows 7 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/333103/is-it-possible-to-run-an-old-16-bit-dos-application-under-windows-7-64-bit)

My laptop operating system is Windows 7 (64-Bit), but this system does not support Foxpro DOS 2.6 (16-Bit).

Is it possible to run this program on this system? If so, then how?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only through virtualization.

If the program runs on 32-bit systems fine, then try [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx), if your Windows 7 supports it.

If not, but [DOS Box](http://www.dosbox.com/) works, then great. If not, try a product like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), install DOS on it, and give it a go. That would certainly work.