# Why does MS-DOS tells me I need extended memory and thinks a file is read-only?

Tags: ms-dos

I am running a .COM file on a  MS-DOS 6.22 boot USB drive When I run it on my laptop the program works fine but when I run it on my desktop I get error 40 not enough extended memory.

When I go to the memory tab in GUI I try to switch none to auto, but I get the error "This file might be read-only". It's not read-only, when I put it on my desktop I change the settings and the new settings are in a .pif I can't run .pif in MS-DOs so I need to

1. Change the .exe not create a `.pif`.
2. Change the amount of extended memory all files have on my MS-DOS.

On my laptop there is no memory tab, the only real difference is my laptop is x64. Thanks for helping but I think teh x64 bit has nothing to do with it I dont eve nthink iits in 64 bit mode because Im using a boot USB. What i need to is listed above, thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to explain what is different between your Desktop and your Laptop.  You also need to clarify what your question is exactly there is a great deal of noise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/333103/is-it-possible-to-run-an-old-16-bit-dos-application-under-windows-7-64-bit?rq=1

Comment: What are the specifications of your computer? Do you have enough memory?

Comment: Yeh I need to run my .EXE files in a sepcial environment

Comment: **Wait, what‽** A 16-bit `.com` file won’t run on your 32-bit desktop, but *does* run on your 64-bit laptop? Are you sure you didn’t get that backwards? `o.O`

Comment: What a mess. You shouldn't be changing memory settings by right clicking icons in windows, for your usb stick running msdos. I doubt that's even possible. There are no PIFs in MSDOS and you don't configure things like that in or for MSDOS! You configure things for msdos WITHIN MSDOS.   like to shift memory around edit config.sys and say device=.......emm386.exe RAM  or to switch it the other way device=....emm386 NOEMS    You configure DOS within DOS, editing autoexec.bat and config.sys though you could edit those two in notepad outside DOS!

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the fact that you are probably using Expanded Memory, not Extended Memory. There were two different schemes back then and you needed to adjust the HIMEM.SYS and EMM386.EXE and/or possibly use a TSR like QEMM. The .pif lets you set the environment if you're gonna try to run it from Windows, but does nothing if you boot to DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, you cannot run 16-bit DOS applications on any Windows x64 architecture<sup>[[1]](https://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application)</sup> without running a 32-bit emulation of Windows/DOS<sup>[[2]](https://superuser.com/questions/264090/how-do-i-get-16-bit-programs-to-work-on-a-64-bit-windows)</sup> (i.e. running Windows XP Mode on top of Windows 7 Professional x64)

Comment: You may want to link him to some kind of primer or tutorial because he actually said *I think teh [sic] x64 bit has nothing to do with it I dont [sic] eve [sic] nthink iits in 64 bit mode because Im [sic] using a boot USB. [sic sic sick]* `:-|`

Comment: @synetech if the question gets reopened, sure

Comment: You can’t edit? That’s odd; I didn’t think editing an answer to a closed question required higher rep.

Comment: @synetech It doesn't. I just won't edit my answer if the question needs fixing

Answer (score 0):

Your best option can be using Virtual PC. It is available inside Windows as a component. Create the virtual PC with 32 bit architecture and you will be able to run legacy application and move it as a file across machines.