# Unix BIOS/Boot Record on USB Flash Drive

Tags: unix, bios, usb-flash-drive, bootloader

I have been trying to learn a bit more about USB drives, and am curious about their MBRs.

Essentially, I open up the device file of the USB drive and give a hex dump of the first 496 bytes of the file. I know that addresses 0x1fe and 0x1ff contain the bytes 55 and aa, respectively, and that they mark the end of the "master boot record". However, I am not entirely sure what the master boot record is.

As far as I can tell, when a USB is plugged in, the BIOS executes the instructions stored in the MBR -- is this correct? However, the majority of the flash drives I have seen have either had blank boot sectors of boot sectors filled with warnings such as "BOOTMGR not present." Why is there rarely any viable code?

I am also wondering what processor the code in the MBR is written for. Is it 16 bit? 32 bit? 64 bit?

Sorry if I am displaying ignorance of the subject matter; I am relatively new to hardware. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: *"what processor the code in the MBR is written for"* -- Since the MBR is a MSDOS convention for the IBM PC/XT, the answer is Intel x86 real mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you're looking at the first 496 bytes, since the Master Boot Record (MBR) has [always](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Master_Boot_Record) [been](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~tschwarz/COEN252_09/Lectures/MBR-Example.html) [512 bytes](http://www.diydatarecovery.nl/kb_mbr_article.htm) in size and is located in sector 0 (first sector) of the storage device.

What the MBR does is tell your OS about the partition structure of your storage device, and it additionally also contains executable code (the bootloader) that instructs the computer on how to load the operating system.

The bootloader only comes into the picture when you actually try to boot from your USB flash drive. For instance, if you were trying to install Windows from a USB drive that you made bootable using software like [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/). You can learn more about structure of the MBR by reading the [Wikipedia article on MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record#Sector_layout).

Here's what the MBR looks like on my NTFS formatted flash drive:
[image: MBR sections]

You were probably mistaken when you say that you saw empty boot sectors. The `BOOTMGR not present` string you see in the MBR is not indicative of MBR not being present on the flash drive.

In fact, it is the error message that is displayed to the user when he/she tries to boot from the flash drive when it is not configured to be bootable.

The MBR has been exploited in the past by several boot sector viruses like [Stoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoned_(computer_virus)) and [Brain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_(computer_virus)) that would show strings like `Your computer is now stoned` when the computer was booted.
[image: boot sector virus]

Regarding your question about the processor architecture for which the bootloader code is written for, I'm not exactly sure what the answer is, but I suspect the code is [compiled using a 16-bit compiler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader#_Toc231383171) to be executed by the processor in [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode) (16-bit mode).

You might want to look at [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/q/344954/167187) for more information.

If you are interested in learning more about bootloaders, you might want to try building one yourself by following the instructions in this extremely informative article on CodeProject:

## [`How to develop your own Boot Loader`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader)

Some additional info:

- [TechNet article on MBR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976786.aspx)
- [Disk signature in MBR](http://www.multibooters.com/tutorials/view-and-change-disk-signature-in-mbr.html)
- [Tutorial on real, protected and long mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45788/The-Real-Protected-Long-mode-assembly-tutorial-for)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, just to be clear, the bootmgr code only runs if I boot from the usb?

Comment: Yes. The bootloader has no other function except to load the OS.