# Run 16 bit programs on 64 bit machine with 32 bit operating system?

Tags: windows-7

I have a 64 bit laptop (i.e. it came preinstalled with Win 7 64-bit Version). You know, I could have bought a 32-bit system but I was looking to upgrade the RAM to 8 GB in a year or so. I know already that I cannot run 16 bit programs in a 64 bit environment, however my question is this:

Will I be able to run 16 bit programs on this same machine if I install Win 7 32-bit version on it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why 64 bit OS can't run a 16 bit application?](http://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application)

Comment: If you run a virtual machine with a 32bit OS in it that can also run 16bit software. Windows 7 Professional includes XP Mode which is a fully licensed Windows XP Professional 32bit virtual machine. Runs old 16bit Windows software without problems but is a bit slow.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the restriction on 16-bit code is when the processor is running in "long mode".  A 32-bit OS won't put the CPU into long mode.

You can also use emulation (such as DosBox) for running 16-bit programs.

Comment: I would recomend dosbox over going to 32bit. you loose 4gb+ memory access when you go to the 32bit.  virtual machine like xp mode is also a good posibility. It would end up frustrating to have to go back to 64bit just because you had a new program that needs the extra memory etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, 32-bit Windows 7 can run 16-bit programs. 64-bit Windows 7 cannot.

"64-bit versions of Windows do not support 16-bit components, 16-bit processes, or 16-bit applications"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896458

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run 16-bit programs in 32-bit Windows 7, even if the processor is 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run it in 32-bit Windows 7.
If you really want to run it in 64-bit OS, you can try dosbox or install a dos/32-bit OS in VirtualBox