# How DosBox runs 8-bit Applications in 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, dosbox

Usually, When we try to execute applications such as a C-language , Assembler in a 64-bit OS , it simply won't work unless we use programs such as DosBox.

I want to know the reason why the 8-bit applications doesn't work in 64-bit OS ?
Since 64-bit is much more greater than the 8-bit therefore 8-bit applications must work in 64-bit processor , then why it doesn't ?

and how programs like DosBox make such 8-bit applications executable in the 64-bit Operating System ?

As far as i know -> those 8-bit applications are operated in Real mode (Dos Mode).

So does that mean there is no real mode when using the 64-bit OS ?

I am confused about this concept, searched a lot on google but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: DosBox is an emulator.

Comment: The issue is not just 8-bit versus 64-bit, it's also that the 8-bit application requires an API that the OS just doesn't provide -- an API based around 8-bit integers, and 16-bit pointers with segmentation.

Comment: Dosbox runs 16-bit applications, not 8 bit. There's no 8-bit x86 architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Why can't a 64 bit OS run a 16 bit application?](https://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-64-bit-os-cant-run-a-16-bit-application)

DOSBox is able to emulate older CPUs, graphics and audio hardware. Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator for more.

Comment: Give more detail next time.