# Is it possible to run 32bit (non install) software on 64bit Windows 8.1 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, 64-bit

I have a really old accountig software which has data in it since 2000 but the software doesn't have support any more, actually the company who made it doesn't exsists any more.
It runs fine with Win 7 x86 but the notebook which I was using the software on died so I bought a new notebook but that came with Win 8.1 x64 pro and if try to run this sw I get this "the software isn't compatible with your system. Contact the provider" message or something similar, sorry my windows isn't English. I could roll back to x86 but it would be stupid because the notebook has 8GB ram so I would loose more than half of its memory.

I tried compatibility mode and putting it in the Program Files(x86) but I still got this message.

So is it possible to run it somehow on the x64 system? Oh and maybe without a virtual machine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that the software uses 16bit executables from DOS era? If so then it is definitely not possible to run it on any 64bit Windows. You may try to run it under Windows XP Mode (virtual machine).

Comment: Your old program is most likely using 16-bit libraries (or is actually completely a 16-bit program). Which leads to: [Why can't a 64 bit OS run a 16 bit application?](http://superuser.com/questions/140953/why-cant-a-64-bit-os-run-a-16-bit-application)

Comment: Easy enough to solve. Use a virtual machine, install Windows on it, install the software that isn't compatible with 64-bit operating systems to this virtual machine, then run software.

Comment: Thanks for help. As I see my only option is to create an x86 virtual machine and run it from there, because I tried DosBox and it says that "This program must run in Windows" Or I could replace my x64 system to x86